# IE dropdown cutoff

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, select, internet-explorer-7

I am fixing ie dropdown cutoff issue with the css.
Its working fine for me. I am using an arrow for dropdown. 
This drop down is not visible in ie7 and ie6.
I have attached an image.[image]

I tried and reduced the  opacity visible by filter: for ie7 but makes the text dissapear. Can I fix it?

Need help to make it visible in ie7.

```
<style type="text/css">
.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 100%;
    width: auto;
   padding: 5px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 0px none transparent;
   border-radius: 0;
   outline:0;
   height: 30px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   position:absolute;
   top:-2px;
   left:-1px;
   }
   .styled-select {
   width: 155px;
   height: 25px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-image: url("dropdown-arrow.gif");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position:top right;
   background-color:#fff;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px #ccc;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px #ccc;
   border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
   position:relative;
   }

</style>
<div class="styled-select"> 
   <select>
      <option value="0">Please Select</option>
<option value="BILLING" >Default Billing</option>
<option  value="Auburn Office" >Auburn Office</option>
<option  value="Boston Office" >Boston Office</option>
<option  value="Central Ave Office" >Central Ave Office</option>
<option  value="Knoxville Office" >Knoxville Office</option>
<option  value="Seahawks HQ" >Seahawks HQ</option>
<option  value="Test Ship To Address Field Lenght with this line 1" >Test Ship To Address Field Lenght with this line 1</option>
<option  value="Zones" >Zones</option>
<option  value="test address" >test address</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Please see:-
http://jsfiddle.net/Pq2zH/embedd

Answer (score 0):

I came across this recently. Apparently there is a bug in IE 7 that SELECT lists maintain infinite z-index. To workaround this, you might have to implement javascript to show or hide the dropdown, it is a painful solution though. Best would be to deprecate support for old browsers :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am trying hard to ignore JS.

Comment: After trying couple of things, I ended up using Jquery plugin for dropdown. Were you able to implement it without using JS?